php Getting the COUNT
I’m looping through a user table to check if they exist in another table. It sounds simple enough, but I’m not able to the results I need.
Running this query tells me if the user exists:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM phplist_user_user WHERE email = '".$person->email."'
From this query I get this result id they exist:

DB Object
(
    [_pdo:DB:private] => PDO Object
        (
        )
    [_query:DB:private] => PDOStatement Object
        (
            [queryString] => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `phplist_user_user` WHERE `email` = 'somebody@gmail.com'
        )
    [_error:DB:private] => 
    [_results:DB:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 1
                )
        )
    [_count:DB:private] => 1
)

If they don’t exist, I get:

DB Object
(
    [_pdo:DB:private] => PDO Object
        (
        )
    [_query:DB:private] => PDOStatement Object
        (
            [queryString] => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `phplist_user_user` WHERE `email` = 'somebodyelse@gmail.com'
        )
    [_error:DB:private] => 
    [_results:DB:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )
        )
    [_count:DB:private] => 1
)

In the first instance, the COUNT is 1. In the second the COUNT is 0.
I can't find a way of getting the COUNT from the result. I’m sure this should be easy, but nothing I’ve tried will work.

The actual code which you use to retrieve this "DB Object" is missing from your question. I guess you're using PDO, since that's in your tags, so you could try PDOStatement::rowCount.

@KIKOSoftware FYI, you should never use this method. Especially in this case

@YourCommonSense You may have a point: "For statements that produce result sets, such as SELECT, the behavior is undefined". Duh... One can, of course use the normal way of getting the result of the count. Another problem is SQL-injection.

talkpoppycock, In addition to the answer linked at the top of your question, please refer  this article, as I smell some issues explained there, Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases

As an alternative to fetchColumn(), you can use an alias (as shown here).

@KIKOSoftware Especially in this case this function will obviously return incorrect information, no matter whether it's supported or not
